# How can I cache AngularJS bootstrapping?

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions

We currently use AngularJS for an app in the context of a Chrome/Firefox web extension browser action (popup window from the toolbar). Ex:

[image: bitwarden popup]

Each time the popup is opened, the AngularJS application is bootstrapped anew. Albeit pretty minimal, this leads to some lag in the application appearing that our users have noticed. It's not as snappy as other menus. My current theory is that the bootstrapping process of AngularJS is what is causing this lag. If you rapidly open and close the popup over and over you can indeed observe the CPU of the browser spiking.

Web extensions have a background process (background.js) that is always running with the browser session whether or not this popup is opened. I'd like to try and cache whatever I can to this background process to reduce the bootstrapping workload as much as possible each time this popup is launched.

What/how can I cache from the AngularJS bootstrapping process?

Comment: The background page is a different `window` with its own DOM, so I doubt it's of much use here. You should start by measuring the performance in devtools Performance panel, identify the bottlenecks, and hack at them.

Comment: I understand that it is a different `window`, however, I figured I could potentially "cache" some of the bootstrapped angular objects to it since it persists beyond the popup closing.

Comment: Sure. https://github.com/bitwarden/browser

Comment: Most of the time is spent loading and initializing lots of scripts, while angularInit takes only ~33%. You can try to lazy-load scripts that aren't needed at the start and bundle those that are. You can also hardcode the basic DOM structure (with text and icons, of course) so that it's displayed instantly at start, then populate/bind it once the app is initialized.

Comment: I'm curious how you are measuring this with dev tools? I can't seem to get a dev tools session open prior to opening the popup. Closing the popup then kills the dev tools again. This makes it particularly difficult to profile during it opening.

Comment: Open devtools Perfomance panel, then Ctrl-Shift-E key (or the second button in the toolbar).

Comment: Oh wow, didn't know about the reload option there. That helps. Thanks! Evaluating the profile session seems to show that most of the script loading is done in parallel (angular.js taking the longest). Would bundling them together really save much time on the front there? It still appears to me like the majority of the load time is spent in Angular and jQuery stuff (I presume jQuery is being called from Angular since I don't really use jQuery much here). And back to the original question, is there anything during Angular init that I could cache to the bg so it only happens on the first open?

Comment: @wOxxOm In testing, I bundled all the scripts/css together (now just 2 file references) and it indeed does save about 100ms off the startup time. Thanks for that suggestion. I still feel like there's more than can be saved with Angular bootstrapping though.